# PHP Form processing and browser behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've got a form on a php page and once it is submited, processed and the user goes to another page and then goes back to the page where the form resides (by hitting the "Back" button on the browser) or refreshing the page, the browser tells the user that the page requested is outdated and prompts for downloading a fresh copy of the page and resubmitting the info because the browser does not cache sensitive information...something like that.The form's action attribute is set to the same page it is on.So how is this done-refreshing the page without this browser behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submitting the form, you should clear the $_POST data by doing a redirect, e.g.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

This will prevent that same data from being sent again, and is called [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Thanks for the reply orourkek, however I have a form that is populated with data from a database ad presents an oppurtunity to edit that data and parse it back to that database, when the editing is done I throw a success message on the same page but if refresh is hit it says that it has to repost...something like that, I'd like to stay on the same page on succsessful submit with no header() redirects.

Comment: @mookar If you need to pass data back to that same page while using `header()`, use a GET variable(s) as needed

Comment: I'd preffer the data to be private and the GET vars don't quite offer privacy, you know plus it is user data and it should not be right in the url field!

Comment: I think we're on different pages here. The redirect happens after the form data is validated. The form submission and all that is the same, but if the data is validated you should use a `header()` redirect to reset the (valid) $_POST data. If you want to redirect back to the same page and display a success message, you must use a GET variable flag to show this message, because the POST data will have been destroyed. e.g. `header('Location: http://example.com/form.php?success=1');`